# Can you use an Angular Library created Angular V7 with an Angular V6 application?

Tags: angular, shared-libraries, angular-library

Are angular libraries generated with v7 of Angular CLI backwards compatible with an Angular 6 App? Also if we create a library with the beta version of Angular 8 cli will that be backwards compatible with an angular 6 or 7 application?

Comment: No, you have to build your Angular library for different versions and install the specific version using npm. So you have to publish versions for Angular 6, 7 or 8 to the npm repository. Tell users to install the correct version. This is why libraries have peer dependencies.